# +++ Submit [ACCEPT - Button] with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am totally new to Python and please accept my apologies upfront for potential newbie errors. I am trying to parse a 'simple' web page: http://flow.gassco.no/

When opening the page first time in my browser I need to confirm T&C with an accept button.

My parsing tool is implemented in Beautifulsoap, but I fail to parse the content. When printing "response.text" from BS, I get below code. How do I get around this form for accepting terms & conditions?

Here is what I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import requests 
import bs4 
index_url='http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer'

def get_video_page_urls(): 
response = requests.get(index_url) 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text) 
return soup 
print(get_video_page_urls())
```

Thanks!

```
     <form action="acceptDisclaimer" method="get">
     <input class="accept" type="submit" value="Accept"/>
     <input class="decline" name="decline" onclick="window.location ='http://www.gassco.no'" type="button" value="Decline"/>
     </form></div></div></div></div></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-30727768-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you can just go to: `http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer`

Comment: please [edit] your question to show "Here is what I am doing:"...

Comment: Use a browser plugin like TamperData from Firefox to inspect the request parameters to be sent across when you press the "Accept" button. Then send across a GET request to the URL `http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer` with the "parameters" so as to simulate the actual user action. Let us know if that still doesn't work...

Comment: One more reason might be the implicit redirection performed by the browser (`302`) when you hit `http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer`. I would recommend first making a `GET` request for `http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer` and then a `GET` request for `http://flow.gassco.no/` and see how it goes.

Comment: Sanjay thanks for your input. I played around with the TamperData. And I got following output when clicking directly on http://flow.gassco.no/ : Status: 302[Found] / GET http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer followed by Status:200 / GET http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer. Pretty much the same for going to http://flow.gassco.no/. Hope it makes sense. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do, I am lost at this point. How can I get around that AcceptDisclaimer dialog now? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular website expects that the cookies sent across to the user agent when it serves the home page (`http://flow.gassco.no`) are sent as is when you accept the disclaimer. You can thus make your script work by making two requests: one for the home page and one to accept the disclaimer. To that end, the following snippet does the job of fetching the home page:

```
url1 = 'http://flow.gassco.no/'
res1 = requests.get(url1)
url2 = 'http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer/'
res2 = requests.get(url2, cookies=res1.cookies)
print(res2.text) # The actual home page
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse that content. You just need to make a request to `http://flow.gassco.no/acceptDisclaimer`.

Comment: That doesn't really help as I am getting the same page again. I have attached my bs code.